# Inverting a BOOL property without using dot syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, declared-property

In this line of code I am reversing a `BOOL` value:

```
 someObject.boolValue = ![someObject boolValue];
```

How can I rewrite this line in "pure" Objective-C syntax, without dot syntax?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with dot syntax. Internally that is converted to the below answers only. Dont hesitate to use that.

Comment: Thanks, ACB, I know that. It was only my personal interest

Comment: just in case (from AppleDoc): "Dot syntax is purely a convenient wrapper around accessor method calls. When you use dot syntax, the property is still accessed or changed using the getter and setter methods."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[someObject setBoolValue:![someObject boolValue]];`

Answer (score 3):

use

```
[someObject setBoolValue:!([someObject boolValue])];
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use NSNumber to avoid your BOOL getting a non-boolean (greater than one) value set to it.

```
NSNumber * currValue = [NSNumber numberWithBOOL:[someObject boolValue]];
NSNumber * yesNum = [NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES];
NSNumber * noNum = [NSNumber numberWithBOOL:NO];

if( NSOrderedSame == [currValue compare:yesNum] ){
    [someObject setBoolValue:[noNum boolValue]];
}
else if( NSOrderedSame == [currValue compare:noNum] ){
    [someObject setBoolValue:[yesNum boolValue]];
}
else {
    // Set default
    [someObject setBoolValue:[yesNum boolValue]];
}
```